# Why does $y^2=(x^2-1)(x^2-4)(x^2-9)$ have genus 2? Why not genus 10? Isn't it nonsingular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If a curve is nonsingular then the arithmetic genus and the geometric genus should be the same.

Using the genus-degree formula, I obtain that the genus of this curve should be 10.

However, the book I'm reading states that this curve has genus 2.

Comment: If the curve is the zero set of an irreducible polynomial - as we have here - then the arithmetic genus of the curve is $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$ where $n$ is the degree of the polynomial

Comment: If it helps to figure out what's going on here, the book also claims that any curve $y^2=(x^2-1)...(x^2-n^2)$ has genus $n-1$

Comment: why genus 2? Any idea?

Comment: This model is indeed singular: if you projectivise in the obvious way, then the point $(0:1:0)$ is singular. The easiest way to compute the genus is by using Riemann-Hurwitz with the degree 2 cover to $\mathbb{P}^1$ with $n$ ramification points.

Comment: I think, that It is convenient to consider the curve as a double cover of a plane curve of degree 6 with 6 branched  points.

Comment: @AlexB. That's an answer - please consider recording it as such below.

Comment: So, in summary, there are singularities at infinity that I hadn't yet considered. I also encourage @AlexB to consider posting the point he made as answer. I'd be more than glad to accept the answer

Comment: In the future I will be more careful to make sure to watch out for singularities at infinity. A lesson learned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This model is indeed singular: if you projectivise in the obvious way, then the point $(0:1:0)$ is singular.

The easiest way to compute the genus is by using Riemann-Hurwitz with the degree $2$ cover to $\mathbb{P}^1$ that sends a point to its $x$-coordinate, which has $6$
ramification points, namely the zeros of the right-hand polynomial.